# Error while uploading pdf file to firebase storage

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to select and upload pdf files to firebase storage in react native. I can select pdf files and display its name on the screen, but when i try to upload it i get this warning:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> Error: [storage/unknown] Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document:1000017646 from pid=9810, uid=10345 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
> NativeFirebaseError: [storage/unknown] Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document:1000017646 from pid=9810, uid=10345 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

this is the code for selecting pdf using react-native-document-picker

```
  const handlePDFSelection = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf, DocumentPicker.types.images],
      });

      // Set the selected PDF for preview
      setSelectedPDF({ uri: res[0].uri, name: res[0].name });
      console.log(selectedPDF);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('DocumentPicker Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

and this is the code for uploading file:

```
const handlePDFUpload = async () => {
    if (!selectedPDF) {
      console.log('No PDF selected');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const fileName = `form_type_1/pdfs/${Date.now()}`;
      const storageRef = storage().ref(fileName);

      const uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(selectedPDF.uri);

      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        null,
        error => {
          console.log('Error uploading PDF:', error);
        },
        async () => {
          const downloadURL = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

          console.log('PDF uploaded successfully');
          setSelectedPDF(null);
          Toast.show({
            type: 'success',
            text1: 'PDF Uploaded!',
          });
          console.log('Download URL:', downloadURL);
          setDownloadLink(downloadURL);
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading PDF:', error);
    }
  };
```